# CloudFormation can't find AZs

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The following CFN template creates simple S3 bucket, then outputs the first two AZs in the region 'US-EAST-1'. The first AZ with index '0' returns just fine, however, the second one doesn't seem to work.

```
Resources:
  S3:
   Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Outputs:
  az1:
   Description: ID for AZ 1
   Value: !Select
     - 0
     - Fn::GetAZs: ''
  az2:
   Description: ID for AZ 2
   Value: !Select
     - 1
     - Fn::GetAZs: ''
```

Error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 1. Rollback requested by user.

Comment: Your template runs perfectly well for me in us-east-1 and ap-southest-2.

Comment: I had this same problem yesterday with a stack that had previously been working. I believe there might have been some issue with the CloudFormation service. I've also tried your template and it deploys fine for me. Hopefully the same, resolved issue.